# «Нельзя объять» против «Нельзя впихнуть»

Tags: фразеология, значение-слов

В эфире «Вестей FM» из уст известного политолога прозвучала несколько пародийная по отношению к классической — «Нельзя объять необъятное» (в оригинале: «Никто не обнимет необъятного») — задиристая до неприличия формула, взамен которой не могу припомнить или придумать подходящую. Известна ли кому схожая по лаконичности, но приличная в глазах всякого общества фраза, способная быть альтернативой для «впихнуть невпихуемое» в контексте о бесперспективности давления на суверенную державу?

Answer (score 2):

Выражение «впихнуть невпихуемое» - не новинка. Его используют:

- дизайнеры (публ. 2019) - https://www.houzz.ru/discussions/5498616/
- путешественники (публ. 2017) - [https://kartaslov.ru/книги/Максим_Степанюк_С_блондинкой_в_автодоме_по_Австралии_Руководство_к/1#p18](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8E%D0%BA_%D0%A1_%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B2_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BA/1#p18)
- грузоперевозчики (фото в и-нете опубликовано в 2016, но очевидно, что какой-то грузоперевозчик «опубликовал» эту фразу на тенте своего авто немного раньше) https://kaifolog.ru/photo-prikoly/6763-vpihnut-nevpihuemoe-50-foto.html
- и прочие люди (еще подборка фото) https://www.yaplakal.com/forum2/topic1320959.html

Семь лет назад проблема «впихуемости» обсуждалась тут: https://sprashivalka.com/questions/a701a74d/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5

Укореннившемуся выражению вряд ли отыщется достойная альтернатива (тем более и в рамках приличия, и в нужном контексте). Может сгодится этакое:

- не члени нечленораздельного,
- нельзя вообразить безобразного
- нельзя осмыслить бессмысленного,
- нельзя обойти необходимого?

Comment: Спасибо за труд, хотя нечто близкое мелькнуло только однажды — про Герасима и Буратино — типа: «Успокойся, он же деревянный».